# Accessing website out side the Vmware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Id like to ask you a question and i appreciate your valuable time. 
My website is hosted in a guest system Ubuntu inside Vmware10, how can i access my website outside the Vmware?
Thanks for giving my question your attention.

Comment: It depends of the network configuration of your virtual machine, see [documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_component.html)

Comment: Be specific please, which field from these: 
Virtual switch
Bridge
Host Virtual Adapter
NAT Device
DHCP Server
Network Adapter

Comment: Get the IP address of your Ubuntu with `sudo ifconfig` and the IP address of your host with the utility of your host. It would be a good idea to tell us the OS of your host.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to forward port 80 from your internet facing IP address to the internal IP at port 80.  If you want SSL you will also need to forward port 443.  The implementation of this depends on your setup.

Comment: my website is aleady set to defaults i.e. http port = 80 and https = 443 but i can't access my website outside the vmware

Comment: @OmarAklan you need to **port forward**. Goto http://whatismyip.com  that will tell you your internet facing IP address.

Comment: i did but it doesn't work